# comparing hashcodes with equals method

Tags: java, hashcode

How can i use a .equals method to compare to hashcodes?

```
   int index = key.hashCode() % internal.length;
    for(KeyValuePair i: internal){
        int x = i.key.hashCode() % internal.length;
        if(x.equals(index))

    }

(error int cannot be dereferenced)
```

Comment: hashcodes are primitive ints. just compare them with the equality operator `==`

Comment: okay thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use Integer class instead of int to use equals or simply == for comparing int variables. Because equals method is used with objects only.

The equals() method provided by Object tests whether the object references are equal—that is, if the objects compared are the exact same object.

Answer (score -1):

Use Integer class instead of int. Because equals method is used with objects only, cannot be used with primitives.

The equals() method provided by Object class tests whether the object references are equal—that is, if the objects compared are the exact same object.

Comment: Why would you introduce boxing? Just use the `==` operator.